# adb command to set volume of android 11 device

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, appium, android-11

I want to set volume of Android 11 device via adb command to 5.Does anyone know such commands?

Below command works well for Android 8,9,10 but fails to work for Android 11.

```
adb -s <deviceId> shell media volume --show --stream 3 --set 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The code for `setStreamVolume` in android 11 is `10`. So, you can set the volume using below command -

```
adb shell service call audio 10 i32 3 i32 <required volume>
```

Example:

```
adb shell service call audio 10 i32 3 i32 15
```

For me, `0` is min volume and `15` is max volume.

Answer (score 2):

In Android 11, the same command exists but in a different form. You can use the following to achieve your goal:

```
adb -s <device id> shell cmd media_session volume --show --stream 3 --set 5
```

Notice that instead of `media` after `shell`, we are using `cmd media_session`. This is because `media_session` is a service now accessible through `cmd` now.

Simply run `adb shell cmd -l | findstr "media_session"` on Windows or `adb shell cmd -l | grep "media_session"` on Linux to test it out for yourself. You can find other services by omitting the findstr/grep part of the command.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure struct of "media volume" via command.
But in android 11, you can use below command:

```
  adb shell service call audio 10 i32 'x' i32 0 i32 1
```

Ex: adb shell service call audio 10 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1